# getting the selected item in select1 outside a repeat group

Tags: odk

I am having some trouble implementing the relevants. I am suffering with getting the value of the selected item from my multiple select (the multiple select is outside the repeat group, the repeat group is where the implementation of relevant needs to be done).

1. I started off with a multiple select question ITEMLIST (readonly, all selected) outside a repeat group.
2. That limited my repeat loop (as intended) with the count of the selected items in the list (count-selected(/data/ITEMLIST))
3. I need to use the selected value of the first item(outside the repeat group) in the first repeat loop and so forth for all other iterations (managed to get the position - selected-at(/data/ITEMLIST, position(..)-1) and label - jr:choice(....) of the items in each iteration)
4. questions inside the repeat loop have relevants that if the item selected in the ITEMLIST is 1 then it needs to be shown else skipped, sth like.

I did some searches but could not implement anything.

Comment: Nevermind, I managed to get the selected value. Just needed to think a little. I bound another string   <bind nodeset="/data/repeatgroup/SELITM" type="string" calculate="selected-at(/data/ITEMLIST, position(..)-1)" readonly="true()"/> then I figured this has the value and can be used as /data/repeatgroup/SELITM = '1' . Hope this helps someone!!